# Git SVN, how to compare with remote before push

Tags: git, svn

i'm trying to use git with remote svn repo, I'm new in git and also not sure about the workflow when using git.

let's say I downloaded the trunk to my laptop, and made some changes on it, committed it locally, then after a few days, I want to push the change to remote svn.

1) i forget that which files were committed locally last time, what git command should i use?

2) i also want to compare these files with remote repo, so that i can estimate how much time it would take to fix the conflict. this is useful, because for example, it's Friday 4:00 pm, it would help me to decide if i should do the push now or the next Monday. what git command should i use?

3) can i just push one of these files to the remote?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `gitk --all` for a UI or `git log` for the console magic
2. What does `git remote -v` tells you? There should be a remote branch called trunk or something, so you can then `git svn fetch` and `git diff trunk` to get the comparison.
3. If you did that on a separate branch and in one commit then yes: go to the trunk, cherry-pick the commit and do `git svn dcommit`. Otherwise you can manipulate the history to put it on another branch/split the commits/etc. The issue is that `dcommit` rewrites your local history (it updates the commits with some SVN-related data, like the revision number).